# Adding values to a 2D list

Tags: python

This purpose of this function is to take in a list that had int, str and float values, and print them in separate list according to their types. What am I doing wrong? It will only print the three lists with nothing inside the list.

```
def organize(orgList):
    result = []
    intList = []  
    floatList = []
    strList = []
    for i in orgList:
        i = str(i)
        if (str.isdigit(i)):
            i == int or float 
            if (i == int(i)):
                i = int(i)
                result.append(intList)
            else:
                i = float(i)
                result.append(floatList)
        else:
            result.append(strList)

    return intList, strList, floatList
```

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing you do in the loop is convert the element in question to a string. That entirely defeats the purpose of checking its type. Then you have the nonsensical `i == int or float`. Then you cast the object back to an `int`, which will fail if it wasn't an `int` in the first place. Then you cast it to `int` yet again and append it. Then you check for a `float`, which will never be met because you only enter that block if everything in the string is a digit, which will exclude anything like `'2.6'` since `.` isn't a digit. On top of that, you never actually put `i` anywhere - you just keep appending new references to your empty `list`s to the `result`.

You really need to read the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Until then, this code will simply check the type of each object and put it into the appropriate `list`, then `return` all three:

```
def organize(orgList):
    intList = []  
    floatList = []
    strList = []
    for i in orgList:
        if isinstance(i, int):
            intList.append(i)
        elif isinstance(i, float):
            floatList.append(i)
        else:
            strList.append(i)
    return intList, strList, floatList
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the way you check types and the way you append. Try this instead:

```
def organize(orgList):
    result = []
    intList = []
    floatList = []
    strList = []
    for i in orgList:
        if type(i) == str:
            strList.append(i)
        elif type(i) == float:
            floatList.append(i)
        elif type(i) == int:
            intList.append(i)
    result.append(strList)
    result.append(intList)
    result.append(floatList)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistakes you made:

1. `i = str(i)` converts all the elements to `str` type, this is not necessary. Just use something like `type(i) is int` to check the type.
2. `intList`, `floatList`, `strList` are never modified in your function, therefore you get empty lists.

A correct version could be:

```
def organize(orgList):
    intList = []  
    floatList = []
    strList = []
    for i in orgList:
        ti = type(i)
        if ti is int:
            intList.append(i)
        elif ti is float:
            floatList.append(i)
        elif ti is str:
            strList.append(i)
    return intList, strList, floatList
```

A shorter version:

```
def organize(orgList):
    intList = [ i for i in orgList if type(i) is int]
    floatList = [ i for i in orgList if type(i) is float]
    strList = [ i for i in orgList if type(i) is str]
    return intList, strList, floatList
```